# In VSTS how to lock master branch so that no one can commit to it but pull requests from other branches can be merged?

Tags: azure-devops

I want to enforce a specific policy on my `master` branch. In VSTS how to lock master branch so that no one can commit to it but pull requests from other branches can be merged?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Make changes on `master` branch only through pull request, you should set **branch policies** for `master` branch.

And you can find how branch policy works as below:

> Protect this branch
>
> - Setting a Required policy will enforce the use of
>     pull requests when updating the branch
> - Setting a Required policy will
>     prevent branch deletion
> - Manage permissions for this branch on the
>     Security page

You can set the items for how to protect `master` branch. Such as below picture requires at least one reviewer for pull request.

[image]

Comment: To which policies does "a Required policy" refer in practice? Policies aren't classified as "Required" or not on the page. 

Should it be interpreted as "any policy that requires anything"?